# Display variable value in text javafx

Tags: java, javafx-8

This is my first question and I am new in programming. I hope this question will not be boring for you.

I am writing a version of the Snake game in java for a school project. I am using javafx.

Each time the head eats the apple, a text appears and fades away. This text includes the score (increment of apples eaten).

The text appears and fades away well, but the score always shows the value "0", although its value is not 0 (I can see by printing the score in the console).

I have tried to create a class IntValue to call the value of the score in another way but it did not work.

```
public class MainGame extends Application {

    Snake snake = new Snake();
    Apple apple = new Apple();
    public static final int width = 200;
    public static final int height = 200;
    public static int score;
    private Text tEat = new Text();

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Pane layout = new Pane();
    ObservableList<Node> components = layout.getChildren(); //creates a list of nodes and adds them to pane

    components.add(snake); //snake added to pane
    components.add(apple); //apple added to pane
    components.add(tEat); //text added to pane
    tEat.setText("GG! " + score);
    tEat.setFont(Font.font(STYLESHEET_MODENA, FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
    tEat.setY(height/2);
    tEat.setX(width/2 - 40);
    tEat.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    tEat.setOpacity(0);

Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), ev -> {
        snake.move();

        if (snake.collides(apple)) {
            score++; //score is incremented but not updated in tEat
            fader(tEat); //tEat text appears and fades away
            snake.eat(apple);
            components.remove(apple);
            apple = new Apple();
            components.add(apple);
        }
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a binding and it will update automatically.

Create:

```
private LongProperty score = new SimpleLongProperty(0);
```

Then create a binding.

Instead of:

```
tEat.setText("GG! " + score);
```

Use this:

```
tEat.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> ("GG! " + score.get(), score));
```

Instead of this:

```
score++;
```

Use this:

```
score.set(score.get() + 1);
```

This will bind your value so that anytime that property is updated, it will update.

Comment: Thanks it works. Someone gave me also another solution which is to place `tEat.setText("GG! " + score);` inside `if (snake.collides(apple)) {` block.

Comment: That works as well. But with the binding if you update score from other places it will update as well. So you don't need to have that code everywhere.